# Get Twitter username and number of followers with Twitter API

Tags: python, api, twitter

I want to crawl Twitter by keyword with Twitter API.
Im using Twitter Search API.

```
query = 'football'
tweet_fields = "author_id,created_at,text,public_metrics,possibly_sensitive,source,lang"
max_results = "50"

#define search twitter function
headers = {"Authorization": "Bearer {}".format(BEARER_TOKEN)}

url = "https://api.twitter.com/2/tweets/search/recent?query={}&tweet.fields={}&max_results={}".format(query, tweet_fields, max_results)
response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers)

status_code = response.status_code
print("Response Status Code:", status_code)

if response.status_code != 200:
    raise Exception(response.status_code, response.text)
else:
    pass

#print(response.json())
twitter_search_data = response.json()['data']

twitter_response = []
for data in twitter_search_data:
    print(data)
```

Im getting good results, but I want to get `author_username` also.
For now I can only get `author_id`

I have tried to add this to my API link but I do not get those results:

```
expansions=author_id&user.fields={}
user_fields = "description,username"

url = "https://api.twitter.com/2/tweets/search/recent?query={}&tweet.fields={}&expansions=author_id&user.fields={}&max_results={}".format(query, tweet_fields, user_fields, max_results)
```

This is example result:

```
{'possibly_sensitive': False, 'source': 'Twitter for Android', 'lang': 'en', 'public_metrics': {'retweet_count': 1, 'reply_count': 0, 'like_count': 0, 'quote_count': 0}, 'created_at': '2021-10-05T12:23:05.000Z', 'id': '1445363916457005058', 'text': 'RT @COiNSTANTIN1: @MEXC_Global @PolkaExOfficial Check out @MiniFootballBsc We are bringing together the football and crypto community.\n⚽️Fa…', 'author_id': '1444275133854715912'}
```

Is there a way to add something to my Twitter API so that I can get:
1.author username
2.author name
3.number of followers for author
4.number of followings for author

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close to what you need in your code, but the user information you're requesting via the expansions, is actually being delivered in a second array called `includes`; and you're missing that, because your code is only printing each value in the `data` array.

If you want the metrics (number of followers / followings for each user) you will want to add an additional user field to your query:

```py
user_fields = "description,username,public_metrics"
```

Then, you can either list out the `includes` separately, or do some matching to combine the user object with the matching Tweet. The simplest thing to do would be:

```py
print(response.json()['data'])
print(response.json()['includes'])
```

You can match the user with the Tweet data by checking the `author_id` in the Tweet object against the `id` value in the user object.

There are also tools and libraries that can help you do this automatically, for example, the latest version of `twarc` can "flatten" this data into single objects.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know, is there a way to collect only tweets from one location?
For example, if my keyword is football, I will get tweets from all around a world, but is there a way to set location to , for example France, so that I get only tweets from France that have 'football' in them?

Comment: If you look at the [list of operators](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/tweets/search/integrate/build-a-query#list) in the Twitter API v2, there are geo filters, but these are "Advanced" and are only available in the Academic access track. Also, not that most Tweets do not have geo information (it is a user choice to add geo tagging to their Tweets). You might consider using `lang:fr` if you are looking for Tweets in French, though - that's available in the core operators.

Comment: One question about your answer, I noticed that In some cases author_id for tweet.fields and id from author.fields do not match?
Also, when I take author_id from tweet.fields and convert it to twitter username, its different from username that i get from author.fields

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that maybe you are looking at a retweet or quoted Tweet? Or, matching on array position? The API may not return an equal number of user objects to Tweet objects, it only returns each user in the Tweet array once. If a user has posted multiple Tweets, the user object will only show up once in the `includes` values, so do not try to match on array position for `data[n]` and `includes[n]` as they may not be the same.

Comment: @AndyPiper, I want to get the followers list for a specific Twitter user, can you please guide me, here is the question link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76726633/get-twitter-account-followers-using-api-and-google-apps-script

Comment: I don't have any connection with Twitter and they gutted their API - I cannot help.